# Questionable question: book recommendation

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I just came across [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/3514/37) question:

> ### Can anyone tell me the best books for studying UAV?
>
> It's kind of hard to get full guide from the internet. I just wanna buy a book for UAV guide. I gotta make DIY drones. I'd appreciat it if you recommend good books.

and I honestly don't know what to do with it. Is it a good question, deserving of upvotes? Should I Downvote it? Delete it? Close it? What should It be closed with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I closed that question. Why? A few things:

- The title is asking for the *best* book, which is very much based on opinion
- Even if we did allow book recommendations, they should be more specific. This question, as it is, is quite subjective.

I do agree that we need to better define what recommendations we allow. However, this question could, and should be closed as either **primarily opinion based *or* too broad.** Both would fit.

As far as a recommendation that's clear and specific, I'd say it should be allowed. A lot of questions currently are "recommendations" because they ask for libraries/parts/software. This is a list here (adding to another post for CW).

I don't think it should be upvoted, deletion isn't used in this case (and is automatically done by the *Community ♦* user after a while), but you can downvote if you want to. I'm not going to advise you on how to vote. :)

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious point I see is that it's not about Arduino. A UAV could certainly involve one or more Arduinos, but it sounds like most of the relevant subject matter is more general than that. The best course of action seems like closing it, with the potential to re-open if it's made more Arduino-specific.

That issue notwithstanding, I'd say it's also too broad at the moment, and possibly too opinion-based. It seems a shame to close questions like that, because it could genuinely be interesting and helpful to many people. However, it's not what Stack Exchange is designed for. We want questions and answers which address specific, tangible issues.

Answer (score 1):

*This post is a community wiki dedicated to posting questions that are recommendations. Feel free to edit: just don't vandalize or change content to reflect personal views.*

- [Serial data plotting programs](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/serial-data-plotting-programs)